# Divergence calculation for jacobians

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, determinant

Suppose that u is suitably regular (e.g. $C^2(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$ or $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)^N$) and we write $$\det (\nabla u)=\nabla u^1 \cdot\sigma$$
for some $\sigma$ (obtained via the Laplace expansion), where $\nabla u$ the $N\times N$ matrix of first derivatives of $u$ and $\nabla u^1$ is the first row of $\nabla u$. 
I believe one can show that $$\mathrm{div } \sigma =0.$$ It is possible to show it in 2 and 3 dimensions by expanding but I am trying to show it for general N. I feel I am probably missing a simple trick with determinants but I am struggling to calculate it. Please can you tell me if there is a nice way to calculate the divergence? I have tried induction but it got a bit messy and didn't seem to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain all notations? $\det\nabla u,u^1,\sigma$

Comment: I have done that now thanks

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I tried an example $u=(x^2+y^2,2x(y+1))$ but the divergence doesn't seem vanished.

Comment: I think the matrix of derivatives is first row $(2x, 2y)$ , second row $(2y+1, 2x)$ and so $\sigma= (2x -2y)^T$ which has zero divergence.

Comment: Maybe my description of $\sigma$ is wrong above but I mean the $\sigma$ obtained from writing $det(\nabla u) $ in the above way...

Comment: I got $\sigma=(2x,2(y+1))$. Why is your sigma is a scalar again？

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to write matrices in LaTeX properly. What I mean is that the Jacobian is $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
  2x & 2y \\
  2(y+1) & 2x
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $det (..) = (2x, 2y)\cdot (2x , -2(y+1))= \nabla (x^2+y^2) \cdot \sigma$

Comment: Use \ begin{pmatrix} a11 & a12 \\ a21 & a22 \end{pmatrix}. Yes, I get the same matrix as you did. but my $\sigma$ is different from yours.

Comment: Here I am saying $u^1$ is actually the first row of $u$ which maybe isn't clear from the question. I'll make an edit

Comment: Yes, I now know all of your notations. You wanna write the determinant as $(2x,2y)\cdot(2x,-2(y+1))$, where the second vector is your $\sigma$. That is Laplace expansion.

Comment: I didn't know the name for it but I just checked and yes that is all I am doing! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Never mind. So my confusion is, I don't see the divergence of $\sigma$ is zero.

Comment: I updated the question with this new terminology. Is the following not true? $$\text{div }(2x, -2(y-1))=\partial_x 2x+ \partial_y (-2y-2) =2-2=0$$

Comment: OK, It seems I get something to do.

Comment: I also wanna know where's your question from?

Comment: It came up in "Compensated Compactness and Hardy Spaces" by R.Coifman et al. as a "trivial" remark. It took me way too long to work out the answer. Thanks for asking questions that clarified the problem in my mind!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I think i worked it out now. If we use the Physics/ Einstein notation we can write:
$$\det(\nabla u)= \varepsilon_{i_1,\cdots,i_n}\partial_{i_1} u^1\cdots\partial_{i_n} u^n$$
where $\varepsilon_{i_m,\cdots,i_m}=0 $ and $\varepsilon$ is anti symmetric considered as an n-linear form. Writing this equation more explicitly in the first summed component we see that in the notation of the question,
$$\nabla u^1\cdot\sigma=\Sigma_k(\partial_{k} u^1) (\varepsilon_{k,\cdots,i_n}\partial_{i_2} u^2 \cdots\partial_{i_n} u^n).$$
Then $\sigma_k=\varepsilon_{k,\cdots,i_n}\partial_{i_2} u^2 \cdots\partial_{i_n} u^n.$ Therefore,
$$\text{div}\sigma=\varepsilon_{k,\cdots,i_n}\partial_{k}(\partial_{i_2} u^2 \cdots\partial_{i_n} u^n).$$
Finally we can use the product rule, the commutativity of the partial derivatives on our function $u$ and the anti-symmetry of $\varepsilon$ to see that $\text{div}\sigma=0.$ To see this note that we have a sum with terms of the form 
$$\sum_{k,i_j}\varepsilon_{k,i_2\cdots,i_j\cdots i_n}\partial_{k,i_j}u^j\prod_{l\neq k,i_j} \partial_lu^l=0.$$

Comment: Good work! :) +1